# Why does CMake set -no-fat-lto-objects when I enable LTO/IPO?

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, intermediate-language, lto

I'm enabling IPO (inter-procedural optimization) for a C compilation of mine, using CMake:

```
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
```

As expected, this causes an `-flto` compiler flag to be added. However, it also adds `-fno-fat-lto-objects`: That means that the resulting object file will *only* have intermediate code, rather than both properly-compiled and intermediate code; and that means that the linker must support my system compiler's intermediate representation and be IPO/LTO-aware.

I didn't ask for `-fno-fat-lto-objects`, nor did I want it. Can I get CMake to *not* add this option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a CMake bug... which I have [now filed](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23136):

The developers have simply made the incorrect assumption that this is what people want.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER MATCHES "GNU")
   set(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS_IPO "-flto")
endif()
```

How to find it:

1. Navigate to your CMake installation directory and to `Modules`, most of the stuff is there.

   - It's `/usr/share/cmake/Modules` on my Linux system
2. Find the string or similar string that you are interested in

   - on my system, I do:

     ```
     $ grep fno-fat-lto-objects -r .
     ./Compiler/GNU.cmake:      list(APPEND __lto_flags -fno-fat-lto-objects)
     ```
3. Navigate and inspect the resulting files, the context where the string is used:

   ```
      # '-flto' introduced since GCC 4.5:
      # * https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Option-Summary.html (no)
      # * https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Option-Summary.html (yes)
      if(NOT CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 4.5)
        set(_CMAKE_${lang}_IPO_MAY_BE_SUPPORTED_BY_COMPILER YES)
        set(__lto_flags -flto)

        if(NOT CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 4.7)
          # '-ffat-lto-objects' introduced since GCC 4.7:
          # * https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Option-Summary.html (no)
          # * https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Option-Summary.html (yes)
          list(APPEND __lto_flags -fno-fat-lto-objects)
        endif()

        set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OPTIONS_IPO ${__lto_flags})
   ```
4. Come up with a workaround to implement custom behavior of such coe.

Comment: Also, `-flto=full` for later clang and `-flto` for earlier clang.

Comment: GNU.cmake is also executed by clang. Maybe change `if(CMAKE_C_COMPILER MATCHES "GNU")` to something like `if(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OPTIONS_IPO MATCHES "-fno-fat-lto-objects")` then regex remove `-fno-fat-lto-objects` from it, or similar.